# Displaying a wchar_c and its code point from std::wcin

Tags: c++

In C++, I am trying to display the codepoint of a `wchar_t` retrieved from `std::wcin` in `MessageBoxW()`.

My source file is encoded in UTF-8.

If I declare my `wchar_t` in the source of my program, and give it an initial value, I get the display of the Unicode character and its codepoint in `MessageBoxW()`.

However, if I retrieve the `wchar_t` from `std::wcin`, the Unicode character entered is not interpreted correctly.

Can you tell me what my error is?

I compile my code with MinGW GCC version 6.3 32-bit.

Do I need to use a particular C++ option, or C++ version?

Here is the code that works:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t c = L'−';
    wchar_t *c1 = &c;
    wchar_t buff[1024];
    swprintf(buff, L"The code point of %c is %d.", c1, c);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buff, L"", MB_OK);
}
```

Here is the code that interprets an erroneous character, but it does not give any error when compiling:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t c;
    std::wcout << "Enter a wchar";
    std::wcin >> c;
    wchar_t *c1 = &c;
    wchar_t buff[1024];
    swprintf(buff, L"The code point of %c is %d.", c1, c);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buff, L"", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to `#include <Windows.h>`?  If you just write ordinary output, then it will be accessible to the rest of us.

Comment: Anyway, the likelihood is that `std::wcin` isn't imbued with your environment's character coding until you set a default locale using `std::locale(std::locale{""})` or similar.  If you had a portable [mcve], I'd be able to confirm that.

Comment: What character are you inputting and what character is displayed?

Comment: You cannot read utf-8 files, or Unicode characters from the console, on Windows in C++ without jumping through hoops. Besides, `wchar_t *c1 = &c` is totally wrong. C-style strings are **null terminated**

Comment: @TobySpeight The problem is Windows-specific. Locales and Unicode on Windows don't work the way they work for the rest of us.

Comment: Note that on Windows, `wchar_t` is used for UTF-16 codeunits, so depending on the "character" you might need 2 `wchar_t` before you can decode the complete codepoint properly. You should read the user's input using a `std::wstring` instead, and then decode it accordingly

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's a good remark, however, at this point in time the goal is to to be able to read *anything* into wide-char *anything*.

Comment: @n.m. All the more reason to read the user's input using a `std::wstring` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Go ahead, give me a working method to use wide anything. Characters or strings or golden dragon eggs, whatever.

Comment: @n.m. something like this: `std::wstring s; std::wcin >> s; uint32_t cp; if ((s.size() > 1) && (s[0] >= 0xD800) && (s[0] <= 0xDBFF)) { cp = ((uint32_t(s[0]) - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (uint32_t(s[1]) - 0xDC00) + 0x10000; s.resize(2); } else { cp = uint32_t(s[0]); s.resize(1); } wchar_t buff[1024]; swprintf(buff, L"The codepoint of %s is %u.", s.c_str(), cp); MessageBoxW(NULL, buff, L"", MB_OK);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Let's concentrate on this part `std::wstring s; std::wcin >> s`. Have you actually done this on Windows? Did it work?

Comment: The `swprintf` call causes undefined behaviour by using argument of type `wchar_t *` with format specifier `%c`

Comment: @n.m. There are tons of questions on StackOverflow about working with Unicode input/output in C++. Ultimately, I ended up having to use `ReadConsole()` to read the input, and then the rest of the code I showed works

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's what I mean by jumping through hoops. `ReadConsole` is `ReadConsole`, it is not `wcin`, it works only with the console. OP has a *file* encoded in UTF-8. Can you show me something that works with console *and* any file?

Comment: @n.m. Files are easier to work with than the console. Just `imbue()` an appropriate locale into a file stream. Plenty of examples of that. However, nothing in the OP's question says a file is being read from, only the console

Comment: I am the person who asked the question of this topic. @RemyLebeau, Could you give me an example of using ReadConsole to retrieve the user input? To answer the question about the character I want to write, there are among others the characters α, β and so on...

Comment: @RemyLebeau "My source file is encoded in UTF-8". And what locale is that, may I ask you? Windows locales do not contain encoding specifications, they are language/country identifiers.

Comment: @n.m, The language of my Windows is fr_FR. I don't understand why when I put the value of the wide character in the source file, it works correctly and when it is retrieved from std::wcin, it doesn't work properly. I'm waiting for Rémy's answer, maybe I should use SetConSoleCP (CP_UTF8)?

Comment: Unicode on Windows is broken beyond repair, that's why. I suggest reading bytes (narrow characters), not `wchar_t`. Convert bytes to UTF-32 yourself, bypassing `wchar_t`. You may need to call `SetConsoleCP` if your input is from console (and probably reset it back to the original value at program exit).

Comment: @ab92 `wstring s; wchar_t buffer[4] = {}; DWORD numRead = 0; if (ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), buffer, 4, &numRead, NULL)) { s.append(Buffer, numRead); }` and then use the rest of the code I showed earlier to parse `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it!

Many thanks to @RemyLebeau and @n.m for their help.

I only needed the last part of the code given by @RemyLebeau.

Here is the code that works here very well with any typed character.

P.S. It's missing the verification of the size of the string entered by the user, he must enter only one character.

Any idea of correction or improvement would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::wcout << "Enter a wchar";
    std::wstring s;
    wchar_t buffer[4] = {};
    DWORD numRead = 0;
    if (ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), buffer, 4, &numRead, NULL))
    {
        s.append(buffer, numRead);
    }
    wchar_t buff[1024];
    const wchar_t* c = s.c_str();
    swprintf(buff, L"The codepoint of %s is %u.", c, *c);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buff, L"", MB_OK);
}
```

Best regards.